# Assign value to variable based on distribution table

Tags: sas

I wanted to solve the following Problem:
I just want to create a large column (Let's say of Dimension 20000).
In this column I wanted to reproduce the letters "A"-"I" based on a probability.
e.g if the probability of the appearance of "A" is 9%, then exactly 9% of These 20000 observations would have "A" in this column. 
If the appearance of "E" is 20%, then 20% of this column should be filled with "E" and so on...

I'm a newbie in SAS as to why I unfortunately have no code as an example..
I created the frequency table for These letters already, so I could use this one to generate my column.

I would be extremely grateful for any help!
Thanks!

Comment: is it one observation with large column or many observations with one char column?

Comment: To be clear, you mean "exactly" or you mean "approximately"?  Do you want random data, or do you want non-random data?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to generate a series of random numbers using the `RAND()` function with the TABLE distriubtion.  You can then use the number generated to pick which letter.

```
data test;
 do sample=1 to 10 ;
   int=rand('table',0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3);
   char=byte(rank('A')-1+int);
   output;
 end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, that is what I needed. I thought about writing if conditions after generating random numbers, but this is so much more efficient!

Comment: but in this case it will not be exactly

Comment: @Lee Yes. This will generate a sample from that probability distribution and is such any particular sample will not have exactly that distribution on the letters.

Comment: [RAND Tabled Distribution](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0fpeei0opypg8n1b06qe4r040lv.htm&locale=en#p0rssof65ddoyyn1s3kfdap849lr)

Answer (score 0):

If it's doesn't matter in what order letters are in column:

```
data have;
input symbol $1. prob;
datalines4;
A  0.1
B  0.2
C  0.3
D  0.4
;;;;
run;

%let length_of_column=100;

data want(keep=column);
   length column $&length_of_column. c $&length_of_column.;
   set have nobs=nobs;
   retain c;
   do j=1 to prob*&length_of_column;
      column=strip(symbol) || strip(c);
      c=column;
   end;
   if _n_ =nobs then output;
run;
```

So, input is:

```
+--------+------+
| symbol | prob |
+--------+------+
| A      | 0.1  |
+--------+------+
| B      | 0.2  |
+--------+------+
| C      | 0.3  |
+--------+------+
| D      | 0.4  |
+--------+------+
```

The sum of prob variable must be equals 1. The macro variable `length_of_column` must be less or equal 32767 (according to sas limit).

Output(length=100):

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| c                                                                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAA |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want to store letters like one letter in one row you can use this solution(there is no limit to num of obs):

```
%let length_of_column=10;
data want(keep=column);
   length column $&length_of_column.;
   set have;
   do j=1 to prob*&length_of_column;
      column=strip(symbol);
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Output(input the same,length=10):

```
+--------+
| column |
+--------+
| A      |
+--------+
| B      |
+--------+
| B      |
+--------+
| C      |
+--------+
| C      |
+--------+
| C      |
+--------+
| D      |
+--------+
| D      |
+--------+
| D      |
+--------+
| D      |
+--------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're using the macro language here - it seems easier to do this just using a data step, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that *exactly*, not randomly selected, this is trivial, given the input dataset.

```
data probs;
  input char $ prob;
datalines;
A .2
B .3
C .25
D .1
E .1
F .05
;;;;
run;

%let dataset_size=20000;

data want;
  set probs;
  do _n_ = 1 to floor(&dataset_size. * prob);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Just iterate over the percentage dataset.  Here "probability" is not used correctly, really it is "percentage".

This might commonly be done to create an initial dataset to subsample from, for example (which you might use `proc surveyselect` to generate subsamples).